# Controls alignment issue in asp.net page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I would much appreciate if someone helps me out. I am new to asp.net as this might seem a simple question to you rather. But I am stuck.
I have a web form and at the back a master page. The header, menu, site-content(white area), footer are all in the master page, I have placed the contentplaceholder in the site-content of the master page. 
What I want to do is I want to place the "[LoginName]" and The HyperLink "Logout" at the top right corner of the contentplaceholder with some space inbetween.  My problem is when I start to zoom-in/ zoom-out the page in a browser the two controls( LoginName, HyperLink) seem to move from their places to the right.
 So Is there a way to keep them in-place every time no matter I zoom-in / zoom-out the page in browser ?
I hope you get my question. Waiting for an answer.
Thank You.
My code will follow.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/AdminMasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AdminHome.aspx.cs" Inherits="OLibraryManagementSystem.Pages.Admin.AdminHome" %>

<asp:Content ID="AdminContent1" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminContentPlaceHolder"  runat="server">

    <div style=" width:auto; height:550px; position:relative;">

    <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" Font-Overline="false" FormatString="Welcome! [LoginName]" Font-Size="16px" ForeColor="Black" Style=" position: absolute; left: 70%; top: 2%;" />

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Width="40px" NavigateUrl="~/Index.aspx" Style="  position: absolute; left: 91%; top: 2%;">Logout</asp:HyperLink>

    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: try with Set the body position to relative.

Comment: Your div position is relative, to the content place holder. Likely, the content place holder(div) is growing as you zoom in and out. Use firefox + firebug to verify what is happening as you zoom in and out.

Comment: thanks il work on your suggestions.